# Best way to pipe a program that reads only one line of input

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have a command cmd1 that reads one line of input from standard input and produces one line of output. I also have another command cmd2 which produces multiple lines of output. How do I pipe these two commands in linux so that cmd1 is executed for each line produced by cmd2? If I simply do:

```
# cmd2 | cmd1
```

cmd1 will take only the first line of output from cmd2, produce one line of output and then close. I know I can use an interpreter like perl to do the job, but I wonder if there's a clean way to do it using bash script only.

Thanks

Comment: as an aside to the sufficient while loops posted, i would recommend you check out xargs and/or gnu parallel as it will accomplish the same thing while you giving you more options, such as running cmd1 in parallel

Comment: @frankc, xargs would be helpful if `cmd1` took command line parameters, but as it reads from stdin `while read` is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: @glenn of course you are right. I was not really thinking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line" | cmd1
done < <(cmd2)
```

Should preserve whitespace in lines. (The `-r` in `read` is to go into ["raw" mode](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) to prevent backslash interpretation.)

Comment: Thanks @glenn. (IFS prevented word splitting, but hadn't thought about globbing...)

Comment: Right, I missed the IFS. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd2 | while read line; do echo $line | cmd1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that multiple `cmd1` can be run in parallel.

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
cmd2 | parallel --pipe -N1 cmd1
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd2 | awk '{ system( "echo " $1 " | cmd1" ) }'
```

A usable example, I validate the ownership/permissions of the `.htaccess` files across all sites.

```
find /var/www/html/ -name .htaccess | awk '{ system( "ls -lA " $1 ) }'
```